# Kamailio with MySQL and FreeRADIUS

Tags: sip, voip, freeradius, kamailio

I have installed `Kamailio` with `MySQL` and it works! great but now i want accounting feature for billing so planning to install `FreeRADIUS`.

**Question:**

- currently all users/password stored in MySQL DB so how FreeRADIUS get those users info and do accounting?
- How do i tell FreeRADIUS use Kamailio/MySQL DB to locate user info?

Answer (score 0):

You have setup freeradius with mysql and setup mysql query for check your password.

http://wiki.freeradius.org/guide/SQL-HOWTO